# PHP mock test not working at the method call part inside PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm, tdd

I'm running PHP 8 on PHPStorm, and I'm trying to create a test for a function that returns an IP string. I'm using PHPUnit & PHPMock

I have the following code inside my test:

```
$UserIpAddress = $this->getFunctionMock(__NAMESPACE__, 'ip_request');
        $UserIpAddress->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRealIpAddr')
            ->willReturn('127.0.0.1');
```

My error is

```
Method name is already configured
```

Yet when I remove it, I get an error that it's expected to be called.

I have copied and pasted the function name, and it definitely is inside the correct class.

My namespaces are correct, and the actual page that uses the function works fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! After a ton of checking various options, the code that should go in the test file is

```
$local = new ip_request();
        $this->assertEquals('127.0.0.1', $local->getRealIpAddr());
```

and inside the actual class file

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '127.0.0.1';
```

I don't think the `?? '127.0.0.1'` should be left in for production though.

Comment: FYI: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will naturally be empty when run in CLI environment (which is where PHPUnit tests are running). The same with other `$_SERVER` indexes that are filled only when run under a web server (e.g. HTTPS status etc). Therefore `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? '127.0.0.1'` makes sense for you here.

Comment: If you need to test the `getRealIpAddr()` method logic (that it detects the right IP based on what headers were) then you need to manually supply different IPs (have custom content for `$_SERVER` just for testing this method). I suggest checking: 1) how to backup/restore global state (which is what `$_SERVER` is) in PHPUnit: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html#global-state

Comment: 2) as well as looks how popular frameworks may be testing this (e.g. Symfony https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/5.3/Tests/RequestTest.php#L990 -- may not be the best though as it uses abstractions that hides the hard "globals" part -- it's all done via `Request` instance that can be initialized using custom data in the tests .. so it's easy to test this). You may want to write your `ip_request()` class differently (accept content of the `$_SERVER` as a parameter in constructor and keep it inside the class -- so in a your PHPUnit tests you can pass custom data)